# How do I uninstall cargo-add?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I installed `cargo-add` with the command `cargo install cargo-add`. Now that `cargo-add` is a deprecated project, I want to remove it. I tried

```
$ cargo uninstall cargo-add
error: package id specification `cargo-add` matched no packages
```

I also tried `git clone https://github.com/withoutboats/cargo-add && cd cargo-add && cargo uninstall`, but also failed:

```
$ cargo uninstall
error: Invalid arguments.

Usage:
    cargo uninstall [options] <spec>
    cargo uninstall (-h | --help)
```

what kind of spec does `cargo uninstall` want to remove `cargo-add`?

```
$ which cargo-add
$HOME/.cargo/bin/cargo-add
```

Comment: Do you also have a command called `cargo-rm`?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, I have, but `cargo-rm cargo-add` tells `Invalid argument`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cargo-add` is typically a tool that is part of the crate called [cargo-edit](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit)

If you have cargo-edit installed and want to remove it, then just run this command:

```
cargo uninstall cargo-edit
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I have [a binary called `cargo-rm`]

The [cargo-add](https://github.com/withoutboats/cargo-add) tool *never* had a binary called `cargo-rm`.

cargo-edit installs three binaries: `cargo-add`, `cargo-list`, `cargo-rm`. 
cargo-add only installs itself: `cargo-add`.

If you have `cargo-rm`, then you've already installed cargo-edit. Since they provide the same binary name, you cannot install one over the other. I therefore deduce you don't actually have cargo-add installed but have already switched to cargo-edit.

You can check the help text of the two to verify.

**cargo-add**

```
cargo add --help
```

> Add a dependency to the crate's Cargo.toml file. If no source is
>   specified, the source will be set to a wild-card version dependency
>   from the source's default crate registry.

**cargo-edit**

```
cargo add --help
```

> This command allows you to add a dependency to a Cargo.toml manifest
>   file. If  is a github or gitlab repository URL, or a local
>   path, `cargo add` will try to automatically get the crate name and set
>   the appropriate `--git` or `--path` value.

Comment: My `cargo add --help` only has a one line description "Add dependencies to a Cargo.toml manifest file"